# Hibernate saving (inner?) class variables

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jboss

Not really sure how to word the question, but I'm using Hibernate to store certain variables of my `Player` class. But, inside that class we have an instance of `Appearance` that I want to save variables from as well.

Here's my [hibernate.cfg.xml (pastebin)](http://pastebin.com/raw/RN4Dgz88) and here is my [Player.hbm.xml (pastebin)](http://pastebin.com/raw/64BFQ0c9).

Just to not miss out on anything the [SQL (pastebin)](http://pastebin.com/raw/aGziaYQ3) for setting up my database ("primaryKey" auto-increments)

(primaryKey that's stored in Player.java)

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long primaryKey;
```

The appearance instance:

```
private final Appearance appearance = new Appearance();
```

The variables inside of Appearance I'm trying to save:

```
private int[] styles = new int[]{0, 10, 18, 26, 33, 36, 42};
private int[] colors = new int[]{2, 5, 8, 11, 14, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
```

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: I think you need to setup your `Appearance`  class as an entity.

Answer (score 0):

Check `@Embedded` and `@Embeddable` annotations.

edit: ... but apparently there is something about the problem I didn't quite catch, so perhaps TS could clarify a bit more?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11219181)

Comment: I really must say embeddables work just fine for me, whenever I want to persist a class instance that is member of an entity instance.